# Did not find exact example

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters

I am getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Incorrect syntax near '+'.

When executing the following code:

```
DECLARE @Source        nVARCHAR(30)  
set @source = 'Srce.srce'
select @Source

--drop table #temp1
select 'xx' col1
INTO #temp
from @Source + .dbo.table1
```

Comment: What is the database name?

Comment: See http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass the name of database through variable.
If you want to forward the name of the database using the variable you have to use dynamic SQL.